# optee-os_gt.bb, cherry-pick failed

Tags: yocto, bitbake

during the bitbake for my Renesas board (H3SK) I get this error message about an fatal error that the cherry-pick failed during overwriting local changes. I tried to search in Google for some answers, but no success. Can anybody solve this problem?

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: optee-os-3.1.0+renesas+gitAUTOINC+c3f73c1e86_e770203965-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/costa/AUTOSAR/build-ara-renesas/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/optee-os/3.1.0+renesas+gitAUTOINC+c3f73c1e86_e770203965-r0/temp/log.do_configure.5063)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/costa/AUTOSAR/build-ara-renesas/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/optee-os/3.1.0+renesas+gitAUTOINC+c3f73c1e86_e770203965-r0/temp/log.do_configure.5063
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| Reset branch 'official'
| M core/lib/libtomcrypt/src/ciphers/aes_armv8a_ce.c
| M core/lib/libtomcrypt/src/ciphers/aes_modes_armv8a_ce_a64.S
| error: Your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
| hint: Commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
| fatal: cherry-pick failed
| WARNING: exit code 128 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/costa/AUTOSAR/build-ara-renesas/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/optee-os/3.1.0+renesas+gitAUTOINC+c3f73c1e86_e770203965-r0/temp/log.do_configure.5063)
ERROR: Task (/home/costa/AUTOSAR/build-ara-renesas/meta-renesas/meta-rcar-gen3/recipes-bsp/optee/optee-os_git.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4753 tasks of which 4750 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/costa/AUTOSAR/build-ara-renesas/meta-renesas/meta-rcar-gen3/recipes-bsp/optee/optee-os_git.bb:do_configure
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: i commented out the line in the optee-os_git.bb file and it worked. It seems to be that cherry-pick the repo is not working at all.

Comment: do_configure() {
    git -C ${WORKDIR}/git_official checkout -B official 3.1.0
    #git -C ${WORKDIR}/git_official cherry-pick ${SRCREV_officialgit}
    cp -rn ${WORKDIR}/git_official/core/lib/libtomcrypt ${B}/core/lib/.
}

Comment: you can add your cherry-pick as a patch in your SRC_URI instead